# VisualSVN server log question

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

VisualSVN server access log and operation log are not available in standard version. But those two logs belong to Apache server, I think. I don't know if it is possible to enable those two logs via Apache web server? or is there any other free svn server with simple gui and logging functionality available? thanks,

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be [TurtoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/)(clients) with the use of [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)(webinterface). The webinterface allows you to see who did what on the SVN.